# List<T>.Sort not sorting alphabetically

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I was posed this trivia question and thought it was rather simplistic. The person asked me to explain why this list didn't sort alphabetically. I thought it a trick question till I threw it into a little stub project and they were right...no trick it doesn't sort alphabetically. I Googled and everything I read said Sort() would work the way I expect. So edjumakate me geniuses. I obviously don't have the answer.

```
string str_animals = "hyena, cat, elephant, dog, iguana";
List<string> lst_animals = new List<string>(str_animals.Split(','));

lst_animals.Sort();
```

After the sort my list is: cat, dog, elephant, iguana, hyena???? Hyena & iguana are out of order?

MSDN says "This method uses Array.Sort, which uses the QuickSort algorithm. This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal" but hyena and iguana are not equal so I don't see that unstable sort would matter.

What am I missing?

Thank You

Comment: abcdefgHIjklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: I'm a bit confused...you said the results were cat, dog, elephant, hyena, iguana...that IS alphabetically sorted...

Comment: Sorry guys a typo. It really is out of order and the question has been updated.

Comment: It seems that you split by ',' but you are using ", " as a delimiter. Because of that your list of strings would be "hyena", " cat", " elephant", " dog", " iguana" (note the spaces) and thus "hyena" comes after " iguana".

Comment: Just use `List<string> lst_animals = new List<string>(str_animals.Split(", ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trim the values after splitting because the whitespace will throw off the sort (making `hyena` come after `iguana` since `hyena` does not start with a whitespace).

```
List<string> lst_animals = new List<string>(str_animals.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()));
```

Comment: Ok, you've beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using Split, which splits the string into different strings.
Hyena is the first one, and has no preceding space.
The others all have a space in front, which affects your sorting.

therefore, you should remove the leading space by trimming the strings after you've splitted the original string.

```
var animals = str_animals.Split(',').Select (a => a.Trim());
```

Comment: OK but it "APPEARS" that they don't when I use the debugger to visualize it shows no leading space??? WAIT!!! I was wrong!! The spaces are there I was just overlooking them. Bad eyes! Bad Eyes!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
List<string> lst_animals = new List<string>(str_animals.Split(", "));
```

The space in `",_"` is important!

Like it's been pointed out by others only splitting by a comma will have the split string have a prefixed space. And a space comes before letters regarding sorting.

Comment: I don't think use can do that in the split as it is looking for a literal and the space is too much??